# regex or jquery to split string after certain character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string like this:

Franciscan St. Francis Health - Indianapolis

I need to extract everything after '-' including the dash itself and output it in the second line..How do I extract everything before '-'?? Regex or jquery?

The string infront of '-' will be dynamic and could have varying number of letters...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither. I would just use the native `.split()` function for strings:

```
var myString = 'Franciscan St. Francis Health - Indianapolis';
var stringArray = myString.split('-');
//at this point stringArray equals: ['Franciscan St. Francis Health ', ' Indianapolis']
```

Once you've crated the `stringArray` variable, you can output the original string's pieces in whatever way you want, for example:

```
alert('-' + stringArray[1]); //alerts "- Indianapolis"
```

**Edit**
To address a commenter's follow-up question: "What if the string after the hyphen has another hyphen in it"?

In that case, you could do something like this:

```
var myString = 'Franciscan St. Francis Health - Indianapolis - IN';
var stringArray = myString.split('-');
//at this point stringArray equals: ['Franciscan St. Francis Health ', ' Indianapolis ', ' IN']

alert('-' + stringArray.slice(1).join('-')); //alerts "- Indianapolis - IN"
```

Both `.slice()` and `.join()` are native `Array` methods in JS, and `join()` is the opposite of the `.split()` method used earlier.

Comment: What if the string after the hyphen has another hyphen in it, e.g., `Something something - Wilkes-Barre`? The bit after the hyphen in the example is the name of a city, and there are cities with hyphenated names...

Answer (score 2):

> Regex or jquery?

[False dichotomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dichotomy). Use [String.split<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
var tokens = 'Franciscan St. Francis Health - Indianapolis'.split('-');
var s = tokens.slice(1).join('-'); // account for '-'s in city name
alert('-' + s);
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/War7x/)
- [join()<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [slice()<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: False dichotomy?? Had to pop open wikipedia.. :D

Comment: What if the string after the hyphen has another hyphen in it, e.g., `Something something - Wilkes-Barre`?

Answer (score 1):

Probably no need for regex or jquery.  This should do it:

```
var arr = 'Franciscan St. Francis Health - Wilkes-Barre'.split('-');
var firstLine = arr[0]
var secondLine = arr.slice(1).join('-');
```

Ideally, your data would be stored in two separate fields, so you don't have to worry about splitting strings for display.