# Regex match - split string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, split

I have:

0001-2015

How I can split this string to 0001 and 2015?

Comment: you can use javascript's split() function with '-' as a delimiter. It will return you an array having '0001' and '2015' as its elements.

Comment: What language is being used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use regex to do this?  To readers it seems like overkill to use regex...

Comment: Since the title states "regex match" ... `var r = '0001-2015'.match(/\d+/g);`

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Do you mean you want to split the string at the `-` character with regex?

Comment: @CaptainMan Why did you remove `javascript` and `jQuery` tags from question

Comment: @Tushar at first glance the question seemed to have nothing to do with anything except for regex, it wasn't clear form the text.

Comment: @CaptainMan regex is implemented in many different languages we should know what language he is working in...

Comment: @CaptainMan Yes! But the tag `javascript` will make it clear than confusing after removing it

Comment: @Monkey likely because this question shows no research on your part, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607846/regex-or-jquery-to-split-string-after-certain-character) is the first result in Google for "split string in javascript jquery using regex"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `split` instead of `regex`. It will be much faster than `regex`

```
var str = '0001-2015';
var arr = str.split('-'); // ["0001", "2015"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use regular expressions - you can use `/(\d+)/g` regex , this means "capturing group having one or more digits". It will exactly extract both digital parts from your string.

But in current specification of your task using `split` looks pretty enough.